# How can I correct the position of this TinyMCE editor in Firefox?

Tags: javascript, tinymce

I am trying to absolutely position a TinyMCE editor at a set position using CSS. In Chrome, this works fine. In Firefox however, the editor disappears. I am doing this in a complex application, but I was able to reproduce it with a very simple test case:

```
<style type='text/css'>
    div.container {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
}

div.container div.text {
    border: 1px dashed black;
    overflow: hidden;
}


div.container div.text div.mceIframeContainer {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
}

  </style>



<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
Event.observe(window, "load", function(){

function setup()
{
    var myTinyMCESettings = {
        mode: 'none',
        width: '100%',
        height: '9000px',
        body_class: 'TypeRegion'
    };

    var editorId = $(document.body).down('div.container div.text div.editor').identify();

    tinyMCE.init(myTinyMCESettings);

    tinyMCE.execCommand("mceAddControl", true, editorId);
}

setup();

});//]]>  

</script>


</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="text" style="position:absolute;top: 2in; left:2in; width: 2in; height: 3in;">
        <div class="editor">Enter text here</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is a JSFiddle for this test case](http://jsfiddle.net/H4Var/). Compare Chrome to Firefox, note how the editor is apparently missing in firefox... what is causing this, and how can I correct this?

**UPDATE:** [I tried making the `td` have relative positioning](http://jsfiddle.net/Ke7Tz/1/), no change:

```
div.container div.text table tr td {
    position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Do you really need css for `div.container div.text div.mceIframeContainer`? It works without this style and shows the same result. And it works in both browsers.

Comment: @Smileek I need to absolutely positioning the TinyMCE editor, otherwise there is a slight margin at the top of the `<td>` which I can't seem to get rid of. If you like, I can create a sample to display this.

Comment: I am investigating this further @Smileek, updates to follow.

Comment: I supposed that it is something else in real case - just wanted to make it clear.  So, the simplest solution didn't work. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The editor is there in Firefox - it just has a width of zero, making it invisible. Since you're defining a set width for your containing block `div.text` anyway, you can use that value to give an explicit width to `div.mceIframeContainer` in order to guarantee that the width calculation will be consistent cross-browser. I did this in an `oninit` handler, but you can decide what approach would be best in your case.

Setting the width explicitly makes the editor appear, but exposes another issue in Firefox where the editor is  shifted higher than desired. This appears to be caused some elements that TinyMCE creates, namely the relatively positioned span that it inserts a table into.

I'm not entirely sure why it sticks a table inside of a span to begin with, but the offset observed in Firefox is seemingly related to the fact that the span is both relatively positioned and an inline element. Applying the style

```
.defaultSimpleSkin {
    display:block;
}
```

fixes the problem. You can [check out this jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/CXXHL/1/) to see the changes in action.